# How can a table's columns have same width dynamically?

Tags: html, css

I have a mysql query which brings all the records from a table, each record is displayed in a table column:

```
while($result_team = mysqli_fetch_array($query_team)) {
    echo '<td><img src="imgs/'.$result_team['image'].'"></td>';
}
```

How can make all of the td's width the same having in mind that the number of td may change? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You could try jQuery to change the width of the td elements. Use the java script function getChildElements on the tr element above it (it's something similar to that) and then divide 100% by the number of children and set the width of each td to the result. Sorry about the lack of code I'm on my phone and it's difficult.

Connor